# jQuery Droppable: what is it listening for to trigger 'hover' property?

Tags: jquery, touch, mouseevent, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

When setting up a jQuery droppable, you can assign a class (or function) based on a draggable hovering over it like this:

```
$(".myDroppable")
    .droppable({
        hoverClass : 'droppableStyle'
    })
```

Simple and works great with a jQuery draggable by default.

However, I'm working on a solution that relies on touch, and, as such, I've opted to not use jQuery draggables for the dragging part. I'd still like to use the Droppables, however.

The question: what is the droppable 'listening' for to determine if an item is being dragged over it? Is there any way I could trigger some mouse events from my home made draggable as it's being dragged that would signal the droppable's hoverClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `over` and `out` events trigger this option, though I have yet to use a droppable without a draggable to test this. You can use the `accept` option to select your home-made draggable and the droppable should treat it accordingly.

```
$(".myDroppable")
    .droppable({
        hoverClass: "droppableStyle",
        accept: ".homeMadeDraggable"
});
```

Without looking at your code though its hard to tell what exactly will happen. Have a look at the source code for [droppable](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/ui.droppable.js?r=2208), in conjunction with reading the [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/), it should clarify what is going on beneath the surface and whether or not it will work in your case.

```
        _over: function(event) {

            var draggable = $.ui.ddmanager.current;
            if (!draggable || (draggable.currentItem || draggable.element)[0] == this.element[0]) return; // Bail if draggable and droppable are same element

            if (this.options.accept.call(this.element[0],(draggable.currentItem || draggable.element))) {
                    if(this.options.hoverClass) this.element.addClass(this.options.hoverClass);
                    this._trigger('over', event, this.ui(draggable));
            }

    },

    _out: function(event) {

            var draggable = $.ui.ddmanager.current;
            if (!draggable || (draggable.currentItem || draggable.element)[0] == this.element[0]) return; // Bail if draggable and droppable are same element

            if (this.options.accept.call(this.element[0],(draggable.currentItem || draggable.element))) {
                    if(this.options.hoverClass) this.element.removeClass(this.options.hoverClass);
                    this._trigger('out', event, this.ui(draggable));
            }

    },
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works in terms of the question, so this is good info. It was the 'accept' option that was key. Alas, my problem has to do with enabling dual draggables via touch--which I've accomplished with my DIY draggables, but, alas, it looks like Droppables are the same way...not set up to handle concurrent drops. Oh well.

Comment: You should be able to handle two draggables. The `accept` option can take a function callback to handle this - [How to accept multiple items in a droppable](http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/How-to-accept-multiple-items-in-a-quot-Droppable-quot-element-td138053.html). Just to be clear, when you say "dual draggables via touch" do you mean two simultaneously dragged items by two fingers?

Comment: yes, that's been the goal...have two separate draggables simultaneously. Alas it appears that jQuery UI's dependence on mouse events is the culprit. Touch-punch, while great, still translates touch into mouse events, and it appears either jQuery, or more likely--the browser itself, only recognizes one mouse cursor (which makes sense). I did find a workaround for the drag part with 'draggableTouch.js'. So now it looks like I need to roll my own droppable logic to accomodate.